# Delphi Chromium，how simulate click Button on html page

Tags: delphi, browser, chromium, tchromium

I am using TChromium component on Delphi 10.
I need to transfer the text from TMemo to a textarea in html and simulate a click on button on this page.

I have been try it, but doens't work

```
chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.all(id_4).value='+Memo1.text+';', '', 0);
Chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('id_2.click();', '', 0);
```

Basically i need this code bellow but using TChromium in Delphi 10. This code bellow is on delphi7 using TWebBrownser.

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('id_4', 0).value := memo1.Text;
WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.all.Item('id_2', 0).click;
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not enough to help you. What happens? Do you get and error?

Comment: when i use the code shown i can't send the text from the Memo1 to the textarea in html. This code does not perform the task I need.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Memo1` contains the text:

> With space in it.

...then:

```js
document.all(id_4).value=With space in it.;
```

...is not valid JavaScript, because `With` is undefined. And the following three tokens plus the dot, too. You have to assign text to it, so in Delphi you have to use:

```
'document.all( id_4 ).value= "'+ Memo1.Text+ '";'
```

...as literal, because then it becomes valid JavaScript:

```js
document.all( id_4 ).value= "With space in it.";
```

Of course: you have to take care of `Memo1`'s text if it contains a `"` itself.

Comment: That code didn't work either.
I need to transfer the Memo1 text to the html textarea on this page:
https://form.jotformz.com/90325850930657 
and right after that, simulate a click to send

Comment: It's up to you to make sure `id_4` exists as a variable in the JavaScript context. But if you mean a literal `'id_4'` instead then I'm afraid you haven't grasped what this answer is about and just copied code.

Comment: Amigojack this is not javascript... This is Just sample html:
<textarea id="id_4" name="id_4" rows="4" cols="50">
My text transfered from memo1 to here. 
</textarea>