# How to click the mouse at certain coordinates on the form in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, coordinates, mousemove

How to click the mouse at certain coordinates on the form in Delphi? How I understand first of all need to get coordinates of screen?

Comment: This sounds like a possible [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). *Why* do you want to send clicks to the Form? What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? There might be a better way.

Comment: UIAutomation is the way to automate other programs

Comment: I use TChromium and want to click JS element

Comment: @НиколайАгеев: Not trying to be rude or anything, but why didn't you include that information in your question from the beginning?

Comment: This is my first post on this site, so I don't understand all the rules yet. I apologize

Comment: It's about common sense, not rules. [Clicking in a webpage should be done thru JavaScript using DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67046826/4299358) because then you're unbound to scroll position, rendering settings and zoom of a displayed webpage.

Comment: Also, Chrome based browsers do support automation in various ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If form inside your application, it’s quite simple:

```
    var x , y : integer;
      x:= 100;
      y := 100;
      var ClientAreaPos := form3.ClientToScreen(Point(0,0));
      x := x + ClientAreaPos.X;
      y := y + ClientAreaPos.y;
      SetCursorPos(x, y); //set cursor to Start menu coordinates
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0, 0, 0, 0); //press left button
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0, 0, 0, 0); //release left button
```

if not – then you need get coordinate of form by WinApi:

```
function ClickOnWindow(const ATargetWindowClass : PWideChar; ClientX, ClientY : integer) : boolean;
begin
  Result := false;
  var xTargetHWnd := 0;
  xTargetHWnd := FindWindow(ATargetWindowClass, nil); //try to find our window by WindowClassName
  if xTargetHWnd <> 0 then begin
    var xWindowRect := TRect.Empty;
    var xPoint := tpoint.Create(ClientX, ClientY);
    if ClientToScreen(xTargetHWnd, xPoint) then begin   //transform ClientPos to ScreenPos
      SetCursorPos(xPoint.X, xPoint.Y); //set mouse specified coordinates
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0, 0, 0, 0); //press left button
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0, 0, 0, 0); //release left button
      Result := true;
    end{if};
  end{if};
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if ClickOnWindow('TForm3', 100, 100) then
    showmessage('Success')
  else
    showmessage('Fail');
end;
```

Comment: double var in you code?

As a result I have an error: E2076 This form of method call only allowed for class methods (Delphi) on var ClientAreaPos :=

Comment: Don't use mouse_event, you run the risk of interleaving with real events. Use SendInput. As is clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: Inline variable declaration allowed from Delphi 10.3 and higher version. If you use older – just remove keyword VAR from code and put variable declaration before BEGIN as usual.

Comment: @Softacom Sure, but then people ask for the datatype they should use - that knowledge/sense/understanding will get extinct shortly.